# How to use custom offline map in iOS app

Tags: maps, ios, illustrator, arcgis-ios, mapublisher

I'm developing an iPhone offline map application. I've illustrator map georeferenced (using mapublisher), have geodatabase (http://goo.gl/isw6IP) and parking data (shp/csv).

**Requirements:**

- The map should Pan, Pinch & zoom.
- Search addresses and parking (addresses have alternate names too) on map.
- Routing/Navigate to parking/address.
- GPS Positioning.

My Illustrator map is a small area of a city and app will work offline without internet connection once installed.

**Questions:**

- In which format I should export the illustrator map, geodatabase &
  parking data to be used in a iOS app.
- Which iOS offline maps SDK is recommended for above requirements.

Few iOS SDKs like Route-ME, MapBox, Alpstein, Altus, Skobbler, cloudmade, ArcGis iOS SDK, nutiteq etc are using OSM data or their own hosted MAP data but I want to use my own illustrator map and all data will be available local for offline use.

May be above SDKs support what I'm looking for but I don't where to start.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As per the [Tour] there should be only one question per question, but also they should be focussed specifically on something you are encountering and need help with rather than seeking [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: Your PDF map (and PDF maps in general) is made for paper print, and it is good for one zoom level only. First you would need to import the original map data to a GIS system (not to graphical design system like Illustrator), then re-design using with map styling language. I would suggest to try cartodb.com, when this is done you can get it to mobile using (our) Nutiteq SDK. 
The search functions are data-specific and should be implemented in your app side. This is just standard SQLite API implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Since you reached out, I'll add WhirlyGlobe-Maply to that list of SDKs.

Directly loading PDF is not really a thing my SDK does either.  I'd recommend breaking the data apart a bit.  How much depends on what parts need to be interactive.

On the easy side, if you need very little interaction, you can turn it into tiled images.  One the harder side, if you need full interaction, that's more like vector tiles, except the parking spaces look tricky.